# How could I add multiple columns at once in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Hi I am having the data in sharepoint like

| Title | ID |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | 101 |
| S1 | 102 |
| S2 | 103 |
| S3 | 104 |
| S3 | 105 |

Now I have to create a piechart in PowerApps Showing the Percentage of Each title.

So, I am creating a new column using `AddCoulmn(GroupBy,"Title", "Grouped"), "Titles", CountRows(Grouped))`

Now I want to create another Column with the distinct titles and its percentage with reference to the ID.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AddColumns function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping) can add multiple columns at once. For example, the expression below can be used to add a percentage in addition to the number of titles in the grouping that you have.

```
With(
    { totalCount: CountRows(dataSource) },
    AddColumns(
        GroupBy(dataSource, "Title", "Grouped"),
        "Titles", CountRows(Grouped),
        "TitlePercent", 100.0 * CountRows(Grouped) / totalCount))
```

Comment: Hi, your solution solved the problem. But I am also getting an error,  `Delegation warning. The CountRows operation is not supported by this connector`. on `{ totalCount: CountRows(dataSource) },` line.